# How do I return a partial API JSON response object using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, json, angular, jsonp, observable

I'm using the One Bus Away API, which returns a response object that looks like this:

```
  {
      "code": 200,
      "currentTime": 1504150060044,
      "data": {
          "entry": {
              "arrivalsAndDepartures": [
                {AnD_item1},
                {AnD_item2},
                {AnD_item3}                    
              ],
              "nearbyStopIds": [],
              "situationIds": [],
              "stopId": "1_570"
          },
          "references": {
              "agencies": [],
              "routes": [],
              "stops": [],
              "trips":[]
          }
      },
      "text": "OK",
      "version": 2
  }
```

As I'm building my data service, I want a method that ONLY messes with the array of "arrivalsAndDepartures".  Is there a way I can alter the API call so that I end up with just the "arrivalsAndDepartures" array?  I thought I could use the Map method to alter the API response, but I'm not having any luck.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to limit the response from an API is to set up an optional `GET` parameter on the API that returns a limited number of results.

It is impossible to return only a partial JSON payload using JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

How about using the [`.map()`](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/map.html) function from Observables?

Your code will look something like this:

```
this.http.get('yourAPIEndpointhere')
    .map(res=>res.data.entry.arrivalsAndDepartures);
```